# MemoryStream brings half of data when generating a CSV string

Tags: c#, memorystream, csvwriter

I do have really a simple question, but takes a lot of times for finding out a solution. Still couldn't find and thought to post here.
Below is the code for getting CSV formatted string. But the issue is, csv data truncated from 1020 characters. Simply top 1020 characters only show in "**csvString**" variable.

```cs
var records = new List<CSVDto>();
//In here Assign data to records 

var csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    HasHeaderRecord = true,
    Delimiter = ","
};

using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(mem))
    {
        using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer, csvConfig))
        {
            await csvWriter.WriteRecordsAsync(records);
            var csvString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray()); //im getting only first 1020 characters.                              
        }
        await writer.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

Any expert have an idea about what's going wrong with this code? How to get full csv with "**records**" object? I appreciate your worth reply on this.

Comment: You're calling `mem.ToArray()` before you've closed `csvWriter` or flushed `writer`... any reason you're doing it there rather than *after* the call to `FlushAsync`?

Comment: Try calling `var csvString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray());` after the MemoryStream was closed.

Comment: If you want a string, why not use a `StringWriter` ? If you want to store the data to disk, why use a `MemoryStream` instead of a FileStream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first flush/close the writers before trying to read out the result from the MemoryStream.

```
using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(mem))
    {
        using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer, csvConfig))
        {
            await csvWriter.WriteRecordsAsync(records);
        }
        await writer.FlushAsync(); // not actually needed, since closing the writer (end of using block) will also trigger flushing
    }
    var csvString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray()); // <- should contain all data now
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using var mem = new MemoryStream();
using var writer = new StreamWriter(mem);
using var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer, csvConfig);

await csvWriter.WriteRecordsAsync(records);

// Flush the CsvWriter and StreamWriter to ensure all data is written to the MemoryStream.
await csvWriter.FlushAsync();
await writer.FlushAsync();

// Go back to the beginning of the MemoryStream before reading it.
// NOTE: this is not required for .ToArray; but you get the idea.
// It is required if you were going to read from the MemoryStream as a stream. 
// So we include this line as a reminder to do the right thing.
// This is especially useful on SO if you're here to solve a problem
// relating to unflushed buffers - even though you're not using .ToArray.
// Also it's good practice to do it because 
// good programmers look both ways before crossing a one-way street.
mem.Position = 0;

var csvString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray());
```

Comment: There's multiple issues with this answer:

(a) `mem.Position = 0` is not required to get the contents using `mem.ToArray()`.

(b) It won't compile because `using` requires brackets for the variable declaration and a block for what should happen before the object is to be disposed.

(c) Any objects implementing `IDisposable` should be put in a `using` block if possible. Don't ever create disposable objects and let them "hanging" without disposing or returning.

Comment: @7he3rain Are you suggesting that [`using var mem = new MemoryStream();`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using) is an invalid syntax, that won't call `Dispose()` on the `MemoryStream` object? Are you implying that the only valid `using` syntax is `using (var mem = new MemoryStream()) { ...code that uses the memory stream... }`?

Comment: At first, I thought that it might be valid syntax but "pointless" since the object would get disposed in the same statement as being created. But it actually won't even compile.
`using (var mem = new MemoryStream());` however does compile and dispose the object right away, but also causes the `mem` variable to go out of scope right away, so it would fail on the next line with `new StreamWriter(mem)`.

Comment: `using (var mem = new MemoryStream());` isn't the correct syntax. You need to use the C# `using` syntax: `using var mem = new MemoryStream();`

Comment: Okay, I spent a moment researching this and @ian-boyd 's syntax DOES work, but ONLY in C# 8 and up. I still use Visual Studio 2019 which apparently doesn't support this syntax yet. Personally, I don't like the new/added `using` syntax because it obscures the lifetime of the disposable object and makes the code harder to understand. Definitely not helping when trying to explain to someone here why their code doesn't work (especially if their posted original code is NOT using the new syntax).